# Optimal buffer size with boost::asio in Windows

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm using boost::asio for a client (Windows 10, Visual C++) which needs to receive variable length messages from a server.
The messages are very frequent (more than 10 messages per second) and each message is about 40-100 bytes.

I'm using `streambuf` with `async_read_some` in this way:

```
void Client::readStart(void)
{
    boost::asio::streambuf::mutable_buffers_type buf = _inbox.prepare(std::max((size_t)1024, _socket->available()));

    // Start an asynchronous read and call readHandler when it completes or fails
    _socket->async_read_some(buf,
        boost::bind(&Client::readHandler,
        this,
        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}
```

i.e. I'm trying to adjust the buffer size dynamically with `_inbox.prepare(std::max((size_t)1024, _socket->available()))` to use a larger buffer when many messages have accumulated because the client is still processing previous messages.

I found that I can't simply always use a larger buffer like `_inbox.prepare(262144)` because `readHandler` gets called with large chunks of data, instead of more frequently.

Even with this attempt to dynamic buffer allocation, I experience strange delays and accumulation of data.

This is my log:

```
  2017-05-09 09:02:25 <debug> Received 1024 bytes
  2017-05-09 09:02:25 <debug> Received 372 bytes
  2017-05-09 09:02:25 <debug> Received 844 bytes
  2017-05-09 09:02:25 <debug> Received 169 bytes
  2017-05-09 09:02:25 <debug> Received 1024 bytes
  2017-05-09 09:02:25 <debug> Received 379 bytes
  2017-05-09 09:02:25 <debug> Received 1385 bytes
  2017-05-09 09:02:25 <debug> Received 1421 bytes
  2017-05-09 09:02:25 <debug> Received 108 bytes
  2017-05-09 09:02:25 <debug> Received 1024 bytes
  2017-05-09 09:02:25 <debug> Received 1768 bytes
  2017-05-09 09:02:27 <debug> Received 65536 bytes
  2017-05-09 09:02:33 <debug> Received 65536 bytes
  2017-05-09 09:02:40 <debug> Received 65536 bytes
  2017-05-09 09:02:47 <debug> Received 65536 bytes
  2017-05-09 09:02:55 <debug> Received 65536 bytes
  2017-05-09 09:03:01 <debug> Received 65536 bytes
  2017-05-09 09:03:07 <debug> Received 65536 bytes
  2017-05-09 09:03:15 <debug> Received 65536 bytes
  2017-05-09 09:03:35 <debug> Received 65536 bytes
  2017-05-09 09:03:41 <debug> Received 65536 bytes
  2017-05-09 09:03:46 <debug> Received 65536 bytes
  2017-05-09 09:03:50 <debug> Received 65536 bytes
  2017-05-09 09:03:58 <debug> Received 65536 bytes
  2017-05-09 09:04:02 <debug> Received 65536 bytes
  2017-05-09 09:04:11 <info> Disconnected by remote host
```

As you can see, until 09:02:25 everything is ok, then data starts to accumulate and `readHandler` gets called infrequently (7-8 seconds between each call) with a large chunk of data (65536 bytes).

In the end, the remote host drops the connection. The disconnection is due to TCP ZeroWindow Probes sent by the server to my client (traced with Wireshark), i.e. my TCP buffers are full.

I can't really understand why `readHandler` is called so unfrequently and with so much data <s>(I'm sure it's NOT a problem of 100% CPU on client's side: the client is fast to process the messages and the CPU load is small)</s>.

**EDIT:**

I'm disabling Nagle's algorithm on the socket with this code:

```
boost::system::error_code error;
_socket->set_option(tcp::no_delay(true), error);
```

in the attempt to prevent the TCP/IP stack from grouping the packets, but it doesn't help.

**EDIT 2:**

It seems that there is a bottleneck somewhere in my processing code, so I'm not actually receiving data quickly enough and the server's Nagle algo produces the problem described by R. Joiny below.

Comment: Can you identify every single sent ethernet package in Wireshark? Maybe the sending network buffer decides to put them together in one ethernet package, so your read handler gets called less often but with more data. I not sure, as this normally only comes up at very high send rates but to check this won't hurt

Comment: You are never going to get an inbound TCP segment larger than 1500 bytes, because of the path MTU, Ethernet, etc.

Comment: @R.Joiny 65536 bytes can't be in a single Ethernet packet, EJP is right. There must be a problem elsewhere. In any case I will try to analyze the Wireshark trace better and update the question if I find anything relevant.

Comment: Didn't Ethernet move to Jumbo Frames (9kb) when the speed went from 100M to 1G? And that's ignoring localhost connecttions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was writing a comment which was way too long so I decided to answer, although i am not 100% but 99% sure.

> @MSalters has a kind of point there (although even jumbo frames are far smaller than 64K). TCP Packages can go exactly up to 64K size which is obviously shown in your log. Also is the ethernet MTU not affecting the tcp package size, because if the Socket decides to pack all tcp packages into one with the max 64K size, of course it gets send via multiple Ethernet packages, but the receiving socket completes the 1 tcp package after receiving the last ethernet package.

This was the comment. What I wanted to say is the following:

Your Server sends data rapidly = The server program writes rapidly into the socket buffer.

- The Socket then decides to wait for more data with a timer, if data comes while the timer is active, add the data to the outgoing tcp package. As you are sending very fast, this is nearly always the case, so the tcp package reaches the 64K max size.
- Now the socket sends the package, so the OS splitting it up into parts of the MTU size.

> The operating system is passing packets larger than MTU to the network adapter, and the network adapter driver is breaking them up so that they fit within the MTU. (Source: [Wireshark forums](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/24699/tcp-packet-length-was-much-greater-than-mtu))

- The receiving sockets then gets all these ethernet packages, but sees that it all is one TCP package and waits until the last ethernet package is being received.
- It builds the tcp package of all the little ethernet packages and writes it into the receive buffer, which...
- ...awakes your async_read handler.

This could be [interesting for you](http://packetbomb.com/how-can-the-packet-size-be-greater-than-the-mtu/).

---

### Solution for the Problem:

- If you have access to the server's code, do your edit (Nagle) with its socket.
- If not you have to define a kind of a protocol with an end-flag byte or something similar, so you know where each single small package ended. (You still need access to the server :D)
- The error of the connection shutting down is a problem of your client not emptying the buffer fast enough. But this will happen either way, because the sent data x over time is always the same. (10 times ~ 100 Bytes per second or 1 time 10000 Bytes per 10 seconds is the same)

---

#### EDIT:

I recommend using sth. like a thread safe circular buffer for writing back the data in the tcp_client thread and pop it in the main thread to compute the data. With this structure I was once able to receive and save 500 Bytes of data to a csv which was sent to me in 1ms. I did all that on a BeagleBoneBlack with ArchLinux and my (also with boost/asio realised) Application hosting a tcp server.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it seems exactly to be as you described. Unfortunately I don't have access to the server code, BUT I'm also finding a problem in my code: I thought it was fast enough to process the data, instead there must be a bottleneck somewhere in my own code, that might be the reason why the server's Nagle algorithm is stuffing all packets together: because I'm not acknowledging packets quickly enough. So, even if I can't access the server's code, if I get to remove the bottleneck on my part, it might prevent the server from grouping the packets

Comment: Yes you are right, if your TCP Ack messages the server your too small buffer he begins to group.

Comment: I edited my answer with some experience from my project I did once. Maybe it can be helpful :)

Comment: Thank you. In the meantime I was able to mitigate the bottleneck, which was due to the storage of received messages into a Sqlite database, and now I never get to receive a full 65k buffer, and the server doesn't disconnect me anymore, so for now I can try to continue using the single threaded async model (your bi-threaded model, one thread for receiving and one for compute is more difficult for me to be written and maintaned "right", so I prefer to stick with the single threaded model until I can).